# my bashrc contains strange characters (if Ä -f ü/.bash_aliases Å; then . ü/.bash_aliases fi)

Tags: linux, bash, google-cloud-platform, character-encoding, filebeat

In GCP compute Linux I accidentally did `cat filebeat` instead of `filebeat.yaml`.
After that my `.bashrc` contains the below chars and if I type '~'
bash is printing 'ü'.
Need help in fixing this

```
if Ä -f ü/.bash_aliases Å; then
    . ü/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Comment: It's meant to be `Ä` -> `[`, `ü` -> `~` and `Å` -> `]`.  `if I type '~' bash is printing 'ü'`  Please post output of `locale`. Are you using a graphical or text only setup? Are you using `UTF-8`? What would `LC_ALL=C cat ...` output? If you type shift+\` from your keyboard, then the terminal displays `ü` _or_ the file content is displayed with `ü` but if you type shift+\` then it shows as `~`? Ie. please add more info.

Comment: Ummm ... no, `cat`ting a random file will *NOT* do that to your `.bashrc`. What did you **actually** do?

Comment: $ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: shift+` printing ü.

Comment: @nitishkumar : Why don't you just use your text editor and replace the wrong character by the ones you want to be there? Or use the most recent backup tor restore those files.

Comment: maybe not my cat command someone might have done something,  just noticed even switching to another user also seeing same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like your terminal was accidentally configured for legacy ISO-646-SE or a variant. Your `.bashrc` file is probably fine; it's just that your terminal remaps the display characters according to a scheme from the 1980s.

A quick hex dump should verify that the characters in the file are actually correct. Here's an example of what you should see.

```bash
bash$ echo '[\]' | xxd
00000000: 5b5c 5d0a                                [\].
```

Even if the characters are displayed as ÄÖÅ, they are correct if you see the hex codes 5B, 5C, and 5D. (If you don't have `xxd`, try `hexdump` or `od -t x1`.)

Probably

```bash
bash$ tput reset
```

can set your terminal back to sane settings.  Maybe `stty sane` might work too (but less likely, in my experience). Else, try logging out and back in.

Back when ASCII was the only game in town, but American (or really any) hardware was exported to places where the character repertoire was insufficient, the local vendor would replace the ROM chips in terminals to remap some slightly less common character codes to be displayed as the missing local glyphs. Over time, this became standardized; the [ISO-646](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_646) standard was updated to document these local overrides. (The linked Wikipedia page has a number of tables with details. What you see appears to be consistent with Swedish or Finnish or perhaps German settings; slightly different character mappings were used for French, Spanish, Italian, etc.)

Eventually, 8-bit character sets became the norm, and then most locales switched to Latin-1 or some other suitable character set which no longer needed this hack.  However, it was still rather prevalent even in the early 1990s.  In the early 2000s, Unicode started taking over, and so now this seems like an absurd arrangement.

I'm guessing the file you happened to `cat` contained some control characters which instructed your terminal to switch to this legacy character set. It's not entirely uncommon (though usually when it happens to me, it switches to some "graphical" character set where some characters display box-drawing characters or mathematical symbols).

Comment: $ echo 'ÄöÅ' ö xxd
00000000: 5b5c 5d0a  @triplee any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Yeah, there you go, the characters are correct, they are just displayed garbled. The answer already contains instructions for how to (perhaps) fix this.

Comment: thanks for helping,  `tput reset` worked for me. when I was reading full answer was not visible